# How to Create a Page with php code as content in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am developing a plugin that gets input from the admin side like API keys etc and saves as options in the WordPress database. The plugin also creates a page(which customers will see) with default embed page code (the embed page embed.php is saved in the plugin directory).

I have sent this to WordPress for review. They rejected it. So, Now I need to make Menu page directly interact with API (API values stored in the database) without embedding page (embed.php). How can I make a page with default PHP code (to make API call & retrieve data from API)

PHP content will be :

```
global $options;
    $get_values = get_option('plugin_options');
    $api_key = $get_values['api_key'];
    $app_id = $get_values['app_id'];
    $loc_id = $get_values['loc_id'];
    $ulr = $get_values['url'];


$args = array(
    'LocationId' => $loc_id,
    'AppId' => $app_id
);



     $response = 
wp_remote_post('https://www.apiurl.com?APIKEY='."$api_key".'', $args );
    $currency = wp_remote_post( 'https://www.apiurl.com?APIKEY='."$api_key".'', $args );

$responseData =  wp_remote_get( $response );

foreach ($responseData['MenuList'] as $Item)
{
    ?>
    <table width="100%" height="auto" border="0px solid #FFFFFF">
    <tr>
    <td width="80%" class="cat"><?php
    echo $Item['Name'];
    ?></td><td width="20%" align="center" class="cat"><a target="_blank" 
href="<?php echo $ulr;?>">ORDER</a></td></tr><?php
    foreach($Item['Item'] as $Value)
    {
        ?><tr><td class="item" width="80%"><?php echo $Value['Name'];?></td><td class="item" align="center" width="20%"><b><?php echo $Value['Price'];?><?php echo $symbol;?></b></td></tr><?php
    }
    ?>
    </table><?php
}
```

The above code should be placed on a page for the front end to execute and display.

UPDATE: [Kunal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9827613/kunal) Gave the solution to the problem. Thanks, Kunal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a string which will have your content and then you can pass this sting as a content in wp_insert_post (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/);

```
    <?php 
    global $options;
        $get_values = get_option('plugin_options');
        $api_key = $get_values['api_key'];
        $app_id = $get_values['app_id'];
        $loc_id = $get_values['loc_id'];
        $ulr = $get_values['url'];


    $args = array(
        'LocationId' => $loc_id,
        'AppId' => $app_id
    );



    $response = wp_remote_post('https://www.apiurl.com?APIKEY='."$api_key".'', $args );
    $currency = wp_remote_post( 'https://www.apiurl.com?APIKEY='."$api_key".'', $args );

    $responseData =  wp_remote_get( $response );

    $str = '';
    foreach ($responseData['MenuList'] as $Item)
    {
        $str .= '<table width="100%" height="auto" border="0px solid #FFFFFF">
        <tr>
        <td width="80%" class="cat">'.$Item['Name'].'</td>
        <td width="20%" align="center" class="cat">
          <a target="_blank" href="'.$ulr.'">ORDER</a>
        </td>
        </tr>';
        foreach($Item['Item'] as $Value)
        {
            $str .= '<tr>
                      <td class="item" width="80%">'.$str .=.'</td>
                      <td class="item" align="center" width="20%"><b>'.$Value['Price'].$symbol.'</b></td>
                  </tr>';
        }
        $str .= '</table>';    
    }

    // Pass this $str variable as a content
    echo $str;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made a premium plugin for envanto market and my plugin is approved by wordpress after review here is the link https://codecanyon.net/item/multipress-pro-wp-multi-step-registration-form-plugin/20702458.

There is no need to embed for customers you can generate shortcode for this. And to create Menu page you can follow this link https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_menu_page/.

---

Try wp_insert_post function https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/ this will create a page by your plugin in wordpress. You can get other parameters like created page id, slug etc in this function response.

Comment: I need to create a page which is for visitors with PHP content. add_menu_page adds the page to the admin side like dashboard, posts, settings etc. Please clear me if I am wrong.

Comment: Try wp_insert_post function https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/ this will create a page by your plugin in wordpress. You can get other parameters like created page id, slug etc in this function response.

Comment: wp_insert_post () is fine but the main problem is to update it with php content.

Comment: Which type of php content ? can you please explain ?

Comment: PHP code to fetch data through an API call. So, PHP code handles API call and response request and the page (created using wp_insert_post) have to show the response to visitors.

Comment: Ok I got it, your requirement is little complex and can't be explain here. If you want you can reach me personally I will help you.

Comment: you can react me at kunal.malviya351@gmail.com